# Laravel considering a directory as its route

Tags: laravel-5, apache2, virtualhost

I have a Laravel app in digital ocean, apache2 server.

The main domain example.com is pointed to `/var/www/html/domain/laravel_app/public/`

and now i want example.com/test to point to `/var/www/html/domain/test/public/`

but what hapenning is when I enter example.com/test the `test` is taken a route in the first app instead of going to the directory at `/var/www/html/domain/test`

I have also created virtual hosts file,

for first app the document root is pointed to `/var/www/html/domain/laravel_app/public/`

for secondapp the document root is pointed to `/var/www/html/domain/test/public/`

even then it is taken as a route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define a subfolder as ServerName in your vhosts entry. Instead you have to use an alias. Your Apache configuration for the VirtualHost should look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain/laravel_app/public/
    ServerName example.com
    Alias /test /var/www/html/domain/test/public/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

So a call to example.com/test uses the folder **/var/www/html/domain/test/public/**

To make the 'Test' Laravel Installation work you have to modify the .htaccess file in the public folder and add a Rewrite Base after the line RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test
```

Also don't forget to restart Apache.

Comment: But do the routes in the second Laravel app(/var/www/html/domain/test/public/) work?  I have added an alias rule, its is going to the path specified, but only home route works('/') and remaining routes like (/register, /other ..) are not working.

Comment: You have to adjust the .htaccess file for the second Laravel app and add the correct RewriteBase. Otherwise only the '/' route works.  Note: The correct route would be example.com/test/register this should work with the adjustments in the .htaccess file

Comment: Yes I already adjusted the ,htaccess, it is working fine now. Thanks.